# HTML CSS upper label for start and end of trackbar

Tags: html, css

I need to display upper labels for start and end sides of trackbar (input type="range"). Should be done as in the picture:

[image: two trackbars]

Labels are highlighted in red.
Here is a fragment of my HTML code:

```
<div class="trackbar">
    <span class="bound_label">20 000</span>
    <input type="range" />
    <span class="bound_label">3 000 000</span>
</div>
```

What styles should be for the class 'bound_label' to display it correctly (as in the picture)? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Thanks all for answers. But there is one important point! The center of upper label must be aligned by bottom of trackbar (as in the picture, align by green line)! How I can solve it?? 
[image: align line]

Comment: Post some css to look into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="trackbar 1">
    <span class="bound_label left">20 000</span>
    <span class="bound_label right">3 000 000</span>
    <input type="range">
</div>
<div class="trackbar 2">
    <span class="bound_label left">1</span>
    <span class="bound_label right">60</span>
    <input type="range">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="range"] {
    width:100%;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    background-color: red; 
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {  
    background-color: grey;
}

.trackbar .bound_label.left {
    float:left;
}
.trackbar .bound_label.right {
    float:right;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xb1pg5y9/2/)

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to move your labels at top:

```
.trackbar .bound_label {
  float: right;
}
.trackbar .bound_label:first-of-type {
  float: left;
}
.trackbar > input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

plunker: [Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/Lg5tTi0ceDQZ4XNJHbhj)